# How to work with data different from schema in pandas python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am currently using pandas (0.22.0) with `read_table` with names.

How can I address when my underlying data schema changes?

For example, my read_table is reading 5 columns and the data file has 5 columns. How would I tackle changes in the data(when a new column is added to the data, does that mean that I have to update schema when the data format changes? Is there a way to ignore the columns not mentioned via `names` in Pandase `read_table`

Comment: You have two questions in one. You should actually ask two separate questions. One for the first topic: data changes and another for the second: ignoring columns.

Comment: Agreed. I'll re-phrase the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I have here is I am iterating over data files with a set schema with `read_table` and `names`. I do not want to be updating schema every time when the underlying data changes. 
  I found a work-around (more of a hack) at this point. I added a few 'dummy' columns to `names` array.

Answer (score 0):

there is a usecols parameter that you can pass to read_table to read only a subset of the available data. So long as the 5 columns that you are concerned with are always present, you should be able to name them explicitly in the call.

```
cols_of_interest = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
df = pd.read_table(file_path, usecols=cols_of_interest)
```

Documentation for pd.read_table here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html

Note that you can also pass a callable which can decide which columns to parse, or specify column indices instead of named columns (depends on the underlying data I guess).